# How can I make a Django update with a conditional case?

Tags: django

I would like to use Django to update a field to a different value depending on its current value, but I haven't figured out how to do it without doing 2 separate update statements.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
now = timezone.now()
data = MyData.objects.get(pk=dataID)
if data.targetTime < now:
    data.targetTime = now + timedelta(days=XX)
else:
    data.targetTime = data.targetTime + timedelta(days=XX)
data.save()
```

Now, I'd like to use an update() statement to avoid overwriting other fields on my data, but I don't know how to do it in a single update(). I tried some code like this, but the second update didn't use the up to date time (I ended up with a field equal to the current time) :

```
# Update the time to the current time
now = timezone.now()
MyData.objects.filter(pk=dataID).filter(targetTime__lt=now).update(targetTime=now)
# Then add the additional time
MyData.objects.filter(pk=dataID).update(targetTime=F('targetTime') + timedelta(days=XX))
```

Is there a way I can reduce this to a single update() statement? Something similar to the SQL CASE statement?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/), like this

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F

object = MyData.objects.get(pk=dataID)
now = timezone.now()
object.targetTime = Case(
    When(targetTime__lt=now, then=now + timedelta(days=XX)),
    default=F('targetTime') + timedelta(days=XX)
)
object.save(update_fields=['targetTime'])
```

For debugging, try running this right after `save` to see what SQL queries have just run:

```
import pprint
from django.db import connection
pprint.pprint(["queries", connection.queries])
```

I've tested this with integers and it works in Django 1.8, I haven't tried dates yet so it might need some tweaking.

Answer (score 6):

Django 1.9 added the Greatest and Least [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest). This is an adaptation of [Benjamin Toueg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435156/benjamin-toueg)'s answer:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest


MyData.objects.filter(pk=dataID).update(
    targetTime=Greatest(F('targetTime'), timezone.now()) + timedelta(days=XX)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple Example for Django 3 and above:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When, F

MyModel.objects.filter(abc__id=abc_id_list)\
                .update(status=Case(
                    When(xyz__isnull=False, then=Value("this_value")),
                    default=Value("default_value"),))
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you take the maximum time between now and the value in database.

If that is so, you can do it in one line with the max function:

```
from django.db.models import F
MyData.objects.filter(pk=dataID).update(targetTime=max(F('targetTime'),timezone.now()) + timedelta(days=XX))
```

Comment: That would work for me, but I get this exception when I try to run it: "can't compare datetime.datetime to F"

Comment: Then I don't think it is feasible in one line. If you really need one query, maybe you should try to implement raw SQL.

Comment: I get this error when trying to do a similar thing with ints: `unorderable types: int() > F()`

Comment: You need to use a *database function*.  What is the python max function going to do with an `F` object?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45448406/3124256

Comment: Note that this will probably "work" in Python 2 where all objects are (arbitrarily, but consistently) comparable, but it won't give you the result you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `queryset.update(...)`, use `obj.save(update_fields=['field_one', 'field_two'])` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save), which won't overwrite your existing fields.

It's not possible to do this without a select query first (`get`), because you're doing two different things based on a conditional (i.e., you can't pass that kind of logic to the database with Django - there are limits to what can be achieved with `F`), but at least this gets you a single insert/update.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do it with a raw SQL statement:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("UPDATE `mydatabase_name` SET `targetTime` = CASE WHEN `targetTime` < %s THEN %s ELSE (`targetTime` + %s) END WHERE `dataID` = %s", [timezone.now(), timezone.now() + timedelta(days=XX), timedelta(days=XX), dataID])
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

I'm using this for now and it seems to be accomplishing what I want.